# How to limit requests per minute per user?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I Have several forms in my website and I have several pages with intense database activity. I want to set a cap on requests per user. For example, I don't want people to make over 10 requests in less than 10 seconds.

Is there way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 3):

You can likely do this with custom middleware. You'll need to keep the data somewhere (db?). See the docs for how to write your [own middleware](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware). Here's what's available to you in the [request object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects).

I'd recommend doing this on apache/nginx/whatever you're using, though.

Comment: Specifically in your case, if you're looking to throttle POSTs and can't do it with Apache/nginx rules, try this: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2017/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Simon Willison's [ratelimitcache](http://github.com/simonw/ratelimitcache). Like the name implies, it uses Django's cache framework to store the state of the rate limiter. There's also a [blog post](http://simonwillison.net/2009/Jan/7/ratelimitcache/) that details how the rate limiter works.

Comment: I know this is old but, does this support the server autoscaling? like does this persist over to all server instances?

Comment: @richmondwang that depends on whether your cache backend is shared between all machines. If you use a local memcache per machine, the rate limit will be per machine, but if you use a shared redis cluster as cache, the rate limit will also be shared.

However, I *highly* recommend to use a more recent and uptodate solution, like https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/